# rvm-installed ruby: runs in terminal fine, not anywhere else

Tags: ruby, rvm, linux-mint

I have installed Ruby via RVM on Linux Mint 11. It seems to have installed fine: when I enter type rvm | head -1, I get "rvm is a function" back. Entering ruby -v gives me 1.9.2p290. I can run ruby scripts from the bash terminal window fine. However, when I try to run the same scripts from say gvim (I've got a shortcut mapped to "ruby ") or geany or gedit (ditto), I get "ruby: command not found" (in gvim) or "ruby: not found" (in geany or gedit).

Here's more information: "which ruby" gives me: $HOME/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin/ruby. $HOME/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/bin is in my path in my .bashrc. On another Linux Mint 11 machine, where all works fine, "which ruby" gives me $HOME/.rvm/bin/ruby. Also, on the machine where all is fine, I have a $HOME/bin folder that I don't know where it came from, but was created the same day as my .rvm folder. It contains among other things, links to shell scripts in the $HOME/.rvm/wrappers folder.

Comment: First, run `rvm get head` on both machines, and follow the instructions it outputs, to make sure your RVM is current. Then run `rvm info` on both machines and compare the output.

Comment: Did both--"rvm info" on both machines shows the same, with the notable exception of the addition of "$HOME/bin" to the PATH statement (and the accompanying $HOME/bin directory) on the machine that works.
My question is where did this directory come from? I certainly don't remember creating it. It's got shell scripts and links to shell scripts like erb, gem, rake, ruby, etc.

Comment: More interesting info: in both machines' `$HOME/.profile`, the following line exists:
`# set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists
    if[-d "$HOME/bin"] ; then
        PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"
    fi`
Of course, it does exist on the machine that works; not on the one that doesn't.

Comment: So I think I've solved it; or at least come up with a workaround--don't know if it's a best practice. Based on the info in my last comment above, I added a similar `if` statement to my `.profile` file for `$HOME/.rvm/bin`. It now works! Apparently it seems that mint loads the `.profile` file conditionally; I'll have to do more research on that, but at least I'm to a working point now. Thanks for all the pointers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had same problem, you should try making shell login. To make so use the command "bash -l" instead of simply "bash". In geany you can find where to change it in edit->preferences->terminal->shell

Answer (score 0):

I think you dont have your current ruby set as system default. try running this command:

```
rvm use 1.9.2 --default
```

Comment: Sorry, I guess I should've added that detail as well. I have set the default using the above command. Still no worky.